# How can I block all inline use of images from my sites, the way I block conventional hotlinking to images through .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

OK, I admit I read error logs, and lately I've been getting a lot of errors that begin like this...

> [Mon Jan 24 14:09:38 2011] [info] [client XX.XXX.X.XX] found %2f
>   (encoded '/') in URI
>   (decoded='/skinny/url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADgAAAAOCAYAAAB6p...

The error always refers to pages on my site, but here's the weird deal. There are no PNG images on the referring page, there are no spaces (%2f) in any file name on the page, image or otherwise.

So now my questions:

1) What's going on here?

2) Is this a hack attempt?

3) Is this somebody trying to take content and run it inline somewhere else on their site?

4) How can I block all inline use of images from my sites by other sites, the way I prevent all conventional hotlinking to images through .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a broken image reference in a CSS style sheet.

The `url(data:image/png;....)` part is using the [Data: URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which is used for embedding image data directly in style sheets or HTML pages (instead of having a separate image resource). However, it seems to be used in connection with a physical location somehow, which is wrong.

The access log should have a `referer` column that shows you which page or style sheet is the culprit.